# How to put customize decorator in TemplateView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm starting to convert my function based view to class based view. This is my first time of using class based view, so I really don't know the correct way.

FBV's codes:

```
@auth_check
def thank_you(request):
    return render(request, 'thank_you.html')
```

CBV's codes:

```
class ThankYouView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "thank_you.html"
```

Where I would put the auth_check decorator? I try to put it in the top of the class but I got an error. Then I create def inside the class and put the decorator at the top of it but still I got an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

With class based views, you decorate the `dispatch` method.

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class ThankYouView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "thank_you.html"

    @method_decorator(auth_check)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ThankYouView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```